# Google Colaboratory: Timed out error

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory

Whenver I type any command in Colaboratory, I get following error:

```
Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to runtime: CustomError: Timed out waiting for promise
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notebook fails with Firefox and results in a similar error. I was able to switch to Chrome and it works flawlessly with no error seen in Google Colaboratory.

Switch to Chrome is solution

Answer (score 1):

In case of chrome, Go to settings. Search 'reset' and reset the settings. And then again try to execute the cell in colab.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been a reoccurring one even on the Chrome browser. The solution offered by Samreen Khan of resetting the browser settings is the best way out.

However, Keeping the settings synced so no big changes occur in your browsing experience is advised. Also, be sure you're not downloading or accessing any important files online when you reset the settings. This could result in an avalanche of followup authorization and system errors.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of restarting runtime and "Edit > clear all output" solve the problem for me.
It happens occasionally when I changed some of the colab settings during code execution.

Comment: This should be a comment.